# Kestrel Server Error - the application completed without reading the entire request body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I am sending an HTTP POST request and receiving the following error:

**the application completed without reading the entire request body.**

I am setting the MaxRequestBodySize to null just to see the request actually work. Here is my code:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                                    {
                                        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, port: Convert.ToInt32(config["Port"].ToString()), configure: listenOptions =>
                                        listenOptions.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(certFromStore)));
                                    })
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseUrls(config["Urls"])
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();
```

I have not been able to find any information that resolves my issue.

Comment: The error often occurs when the client send a request that doesn't fulfill the sever requirements.Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130175/the-application-completed-without-reading-the-entire-request-body-net-core-2-1).Could you share the code of  Post action and how do you send the request?