# SignalR sending POST notification to Angular Client

Tags: angular, typescript, api, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://rukshan.dev/2019/05/how-to-notify-your-angular-7-app-using-signalr)! But via postMan, when I call put method I got

> Could not get any response

when I call `https://localhost:5001/api/notify`.

**My routes:**

```cs
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
                routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify");
            });
```

**Notification Controller:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using RealTimeMessage_Server.Models;
using RealTimeMessages.HubConfig;

namespace RealTimeMessage_Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NotificationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<NotifyHub> _hub;

        public NotificationController(IHubContext<NotifyHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hub = hubContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]NotificationModel msg)
        {
            _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync(msg.Type, msg.Payload);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Via client app I can establish connection but thats all, If I try to start the listener it also says

> Not found for https://localhost:5001/api/notify

**My client APP:**

```js
private hubNotificationConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

public startConnectionNotification = () => {
    this.hubNotificationConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/notify')
      .build();

    this.hubNotificationConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Notification connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
  }

public addTranferNotificationListener = () => {
    this.hubNotificationConnection.on("BroadcastMessage", (type: string, payload: string) => {
      console.log("Type: " + type);
      console.log("Payload: " + payload);
    });
  }

private startHttpNotificationRequest = () => {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/notify')
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.startConnectionNotification();
    this.addTranferNotificationListener();
    this.startHttpNotificationRequest();
  }
```

Comment: Does calling `https://localhost:5001/api/notification` work? That is the route you have configured, not `https://localhost:5001/api/notify`. Naming a controller function `Post` when you are using it for a get is confusing.

Comment: @R.Richards ```api/notification``` does not work. Having a get request is for the connection if I'm, not wrong. In the PostMan I do a post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deep research I found that the problem was:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

After watching the console I saw that I got the following status:

> The application completed without reading the entire request body.

So I research for the problem and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269915/10581132).

So changing the code above to this helped me call the post request and display the notification in the client.

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```