# 404 The application completed without reading the entire request body .net core 2.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For various reasons, I need to use .Net core 2.1. I have an ASPNET Console App with only a few classes. 
I keep getting 404: "The application completed without reading the entire request body." I've actually seen this a good deal online, but none of the solutions offered have helped my case.

I also tried setting up a GET request, and also got 404.

[The application completed without reading the entire request body, .net core 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130175/the-application-completed-without-reading-the-entire-request-body-net-core-2-1) The answer to this question had the most relevant info, but still this does not help my case.

I've attached my code. Thanks in advance!

Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSockets()
                .UseUrls($"http://*:5001");
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Controllers/MessageController.cs:

```
    [Route("api/Message")]
    [ApiController]
    class MessageController : Controller
    {
        public MessageController() { }

        // POST api/Message
        [HttpPost]
        public StatusCodeResult PostAsync(string content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message. Content: {content}");
            return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }
```

I then start up the app, and send a Postman request.

Postman Request:

```
POST /api/Message HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: [redacted]
Host: localhost:5001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 28
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
    "content": "hello"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Before going down a rabbit hole and just assuming you do want a string as opposed to model binding, does adding a `[FromBody]` on the incoming parameter resolve this? `PostAsync([FromBody]string content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues found the issue. My controller class was not public

Not easy to spot